# Change text in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have following text in my div

```html
<div id="textbox">
  <p>Foo</p>
  <br>
  <p>Bar</p>
  <a href="#" id="changetext">change text</a>
<div>
```

and on clicking the change text button I want the text to be and on clicking the "change to old" I want it to switch to the old text again.

```html
<div id="textbox">
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <br>
  <p>Ipsum</p>
  <a href="#" id="changetext">change to old one</a>
<div>
```

Is this actually possible with the current approach with the help of css and javascript or would I have to structure my html differently? If it is possible with the current approach, how so?

Comment: wrap the paragraphs with div tag and first show only one div, when click on the change text, show the other div and hide the current showing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a text rotator, you can do something like this.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var current = 0;
  var ps = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    ps[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  ps[current%ps.length].style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector("a").onclick = function () {
    ps[current%ps.length].style.display = 'none';
    current++;
    ps[current%ps.length].style.display = 'block';
    return false;
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="texts">
  <p>Saying 1... No #1...</p>
  <p>Saying 2... No #2...</p>
  <p>Saying 3... No #3...</p>
  <p>Saying 4... No #4...</p>
  <p>Saying 5... No #5...</p>
</div>
<a href="#">Rotate</a>
```

Updated. Now this code is very much **scalable**. Have any number of `<p>` tags and it will work. You don't need to change the JavaScript. Only HTML, you can add / remove. Please let me know if this works. I haven't used [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)!

Comment: But would it be also possible if I would want to have a third text?

Comment: It is **possible** with the current approach as I have shown you, but it would be better if you had it in the above suggested way! You just need to change the logic. You want me to do it that way for you? Are you looking for some kind of text rotator?

Comment: That would be really kind, yeah :-) Yeah exactly, I want a textrotator

Comment: @IbrahimApachi Will you be able to use jQuery?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi Ahhhhh! It's okay. Check the updated answer please.

Comment: This is cool, I didn't even know that all this was possible, thank you alot :-)!

Comment: @IbrahimApachi Ha ha... Ask it out, and see it is possible! Enjoy mate...

Comment: @IbrahimApachi If you wanna check out other interesting stuffs, check out my [techie blog](https://blog.praveen.science/)!

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="textbox">
  <p id = 'p1'>Foo</p>
  <br>
  <p id = p2>Bar</p>
  <a onclick = "chng();" href= # id ="changetext">change text</a>
  <a onclick = "chngback();" href= # id ="changeback" style = "display:none;">change text back</a>

</div>
<script>
function chng(){
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById('p1');
    x.innerHTML = 'Changed';
    y = document.getElementById('p2');
    y.innerHTML = 'Changed also';
    z = document.getElementById('changetext');
    z.style.display = "none";
    w = document.getElementById('changeback');
    w.style.display = 'block';
}
function chngback(){
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById('p1');
    x.innerHTML = 'Foo';
    y = document.getElementById('p2');
    y.innerHTML = 'Bar';
    z = document.getElementById('changetext');
    z.style.display = "block";
    w = document.getElementById('changeback');
    w.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

You can use this code to change text and change it back as it was before

Comment: His question was totally different... And your answer is for the previous way.